# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_7 is incompatible with the layer

Tags: neural-network, lstm, convolutional-neural-network

I have 77 columns, with 4 class labels (already one-hot-encoded) by get_dummies.

```
x_train = X_train.reshape(-1, 1, 77)
x_test  = X_test.reshape(-1, 1, 77)
y_train = y.reshape(-1, 1, 4)
y_test = y_test.reshape(-1, 1, 4)

batch_size = 32
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution1D(64, kernel_size=77, padding="same", activation="relu", input_shape=(77, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=5))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(64, return_sequences=False))) 
model.add(Reshape((128, 1), input_shape = (128, )))
    
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=5))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=False))) 
    
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(5))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
```

This is the model summary :

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d (Conv1D)              (None, 77, 64)            4992      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d (MaxPooling1D) (None, 15, 64)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNo (None, 15, 64)            256       
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional (Bidirectional (None, 128)               66048     
_________________________________________________________________
reshape (Reshape)            (None, 128, 1)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling1 (None, 25, 1)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 25, 1)             4         
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_1 (Bidirection (None, 256)               133120    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 5)                 1285      
_________________________________________________________________
activation (Activation)      (None, 5)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 205,705
Trainable params: 205,575
Non-trainable params: 130
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

When I tried to fit the model:

```
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,validation_data=(x_test,y_test), epochs=10)
```

I got this error :

```
raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_7 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape (None, 1, 77)
```

What is wrong in the `input_shape` ?

Comment: Please consider marking one of the answers as correct or, alternatively, let us know how if answers were not useful and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the definition of the convolutional layer you defined input shape to be `(77, 1)`, but then your actual input has shape `(None, 1, 77)`. As you can see, the dimensionality of the axes are swapped. They should match.

Answer (score 0):

Your dataset doesn't match with the expected input's or inner's shape. You have to reshape them accordingly.